# Using delayed Bluebird promises with Sinon fake timers

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, bluebird, sinon, chai

I'm trying to use `Bluebird.delay()` in combination with `sinon.useFakeTimers()`, and I expected the delay to be instant when I called `clock.tick(10000)`. The test fails however because it exceeds the timeout of 2000ms.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Example**

```
// This doesn't work - timeout of 2000ms exceeded
describe('test', function () {
    var clock;

    beforeEach(function () {
        clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        clock.restore();
    });

    it('should work', function () {
        var promise = Promise.delay(10000, 'foo');
        clock.tick(10000);
        return assert.becomes(promise, 'foo');
    });
});
```

Comment: I would personally not use fake timers at all with mocha, you can just `return` promises and then run several tests in parallel if timeout is your problem. Of course, things like "how much delay I should have" should be configurable anyway.

Comment: I get what you're saying, and in this case the delay doesn't even make sense. This is just an example where I've tried to reduce the code to a minimum where the issue may still be observed. What I'm *actually* trying to test is if my function runs a list of callbacks serially - so I set various delays on each callback to test this. And I figured it would make sense to not actually delay the testing since sinon has fake timers.

Comment: Anyway, what you're saying applies to my second case as well, because several tests can be run in parallel since the ones with delay returns promises. I was trying to solve something that was not actually a problem.

Comment: I doubt this has something to do with promises, when you fake timers globally you are also faking them for mocha who will think that 10 seconds has passed and thus trigger a test timeout